# Running a python simple script at startup/boot

Tags: raspbian, python, boot

Can anyone please help me to run a simple python script at start up? (for eg. let the script print hello) please explain me step by step,,,starting from basic steps!

I tried many examples using init.d & rc.local but not worked... may be I had gone wrong! so be precise,clear,step by step starting from basic step!

Comment: Given that you have tried many examples it seems unlikely that a new example will help you.  Why not show us the closest to working example you have tried?

Comment: @joan: friend,,, I have asked this question since i tried many methods even the link u have mentioned...but not working! May be I have wrong with the steps and thats why I have asked for a step by step answer. so please help me with the question posted!

Comment: Please provide more information on what you tried. Also try finding log output(or create it yourself) and provide this too.

Comment: @MKzero :  I want to run a script which prints "hello" at sartup/boot. so i kept this script file in /home/pi as hello.py and used sudo nano rc.local to edit rc.local and added location as follows;                                     /usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/hello.py   just before exit o & saved it. But at start up it gives the error either as invalid syntax or exit: illegal number o!

Comment: Can we see the python code  (add it to your question)? and does the script run from the command prompt (e.g. python3 hello.py)?

Comment: As per the answer to the duplicate question, the easiest way to do this is just add the path to the script to the end of `/etc/rc.local` like this: `/path/to/myscript.py &`.  No sudo, and the `&` is important.  If this does not work, you should provide post the content of `/etc/rc.local` and the script on [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Tell me the format to create the .sh file to put it in /etc/rc.local and my python script is this:                         print'hello'                                                            ie to print hello at boot/startup.                                and tell me the other things also! & somtimes it gives me error as 'permission denied'! @SteveRobillard

Comment: Still Waiting for positive reply

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo bash
```

create a file in /etc/init.d name it like vncboot.sh

```
sudo nano /etc/init.d/vncboot.sh
```

then

```
chmod 755 /etc/init.d/vncboot
```

then

```
update-rc.d /etc/init.d/vncboot defaults
```

if it says

```
update-rc.d: error: unable to read /etc/init.d//etc/init.d/vncboot
```

use

```
update-rc.d vncboot defaults
```

source:
http://elinux.org/RPi_VNC_Server#Instructions | section: run at boot

Comment: Beware that there are pretty strict rules about the format of that `.sh` file, see `/etc/init.d/README`.  This is the more complicated way to go and not really necessary if you just want something to run once at boot.

Comment: sorry @user3599188 i have no knowledge regarding 'vnc' and moreover dont want to use and hope there is still a simple way for doing this process.

Comment: waiting for a favourable reply!